# Coloring the border of a svg element

Tags: html, css, svg, stroke

So I have an svg heart icon. I wanted to make the border of the heart black so I used `stroke: black` to make the border black. But this is also coloring the outside rectangular border black which is undesired in this case. What is a proper way to just color the border of the heart black?

```css
element.style {
    fill: rgb(156, 39, 176);
    stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root-233" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="false" role="presentation"
style="fill: rgb(156, 39, 176); stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); stroke-width: 2px;">
<path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z">
</path>
<path d="M12 21.35l-1.45-1.32C5.4 15.36 2 12.28 2 8.5 2 5.42 4.42 3 7.5 3c1.74 0 3.41.81 4.5 2.09C13.09 3.81 14.76 3 16.5 3 19.58 3 22 5.42 22 8.5c0 3.78-3.4 6.86-8.55 11.54L12 21.35z">
  </path>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D Sorry, I have fixed it

Comment: It's important to add the code for the svg heart icon. Please edit the question and add the svg.

Comment: Sounds to me as though as if this is an icon made of a single path which has a hollow/empty space in the middle.

Comment: @Paulie_D I have added the svg class thanks

Comment: Remove the first path

Answer (score -1):

There is an unnecessar  `<path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z">
</path>` in the svg code. Just remove it. Here is the cleaned up svg:

```css
svg {
  width: 100px;
}

path {
  stroke: black;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root-233" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path d="M12 21.35l-1.45-1.32C5.4 15.36 2 12.28 2 8.5 2 5.42 4.42 3 7.5 3c1.74 0 3.41.81 4.5 2.09C13.09 3.81 14.76 3 16.5 3 19.58 3 22 5.42 22 8.5c0 3.78-3.4 6.86-8.55 11.54L12 21.35z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D I fixed my answer adding the original svg (after a cleanup). Can you pls revoke your downvote.

Comment: Who says the extra path is unnecessary? It's not required in *this* instance but it might be in others.

Comment: In terms of having a single heart logo I consider it is an unnecessary transparent rectangle. But anyways... my answer is based on the original svg, providing a way of solution, so the problem of not using the original svg is not true anymore.

Answer (score -1):

You have two paths and your CSS selects them both.

You need to specify which one you are targeting either by giving each path a class or ID or using an `nth` selector

```css
svg {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 1em;
}

path:nth-child(1) {
  stroke: none;
}
```

```html
<svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root-233" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="false" role="presentation" style="fill: rgb(156, 39, 176); stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); stroke-width: 2px;">
<path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z">
</path>
<path d="M12 21.35l-1.45-1.32C5.4 15.36 2 12.28 2 8.5 2 5.42 4.42 3 7.5 3c1.74 0 3.41.81 4.5 2.09C13.09 3.81 14.76 3 16.5 3 19.58 3 22 5.42 22 8.5c0 3.78-3.4 6.86-8.55 11.54L12 21.35z">
  </path>
</svg>
```